# Passing custom objects to webworker cause loosing prototype information

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-worker

I try to export data from three.js mesh to string in webworker. I have troubles with loosing prototype information. (this isn't problem with three.js, but with web-workers. Generally I try to send objects to webworker and use it in imported script)

This is my web-worker code:

```
importScripts('../editor/three.js', '../exporter.js');

onmessage = function(event) {
  postMessage(event.data);
  export(event.data);
 };
```

In event.data is object with faces and verticies. PostMessage sends correct information. Such as - normal vector knows clone() function.

Problem is, when I try to access data in export() function. Then values are correct, but I loose all prototype informations. So normal vector has properties x, y, z, but doesn't know clone() function.

Export() function in declared in exporter.js and definitions of three.js objects are in three.js.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you put in `event.data` ? Are you sure that `event.data` is really a javascript object and not a JSON encoded object (in which case all functions of the object will be lost) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I can call functions of objects in webworker, but it doesn't work when I try to call it in imported script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question - "The specification for webworkers does not allow for anything but strings to be passed."

Comment: Wow dude, that's hard. I know that it's an old answer but firstly, how could you tell anybody his questions are stupid? and secondly, that's wrong, you can pass simple objects (it'll be serialized and deserialized)

Comment: I think he will be OK. Mainly because I was the guy who asked that question ;)